# How can I send a mail message later? On Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

I want to compose a message, but rather than clicking "Send", I want to schedule a future delivery date and have the mail sent then without my taking action as long as the computer is still running.

I'm currently using Apple mail with Google apps configured using IMAP syncing.

The [answers here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45604/how-can-i-send-a-mail-message-later) using [Mail Scripts](http://andreasamann.com/MacOSX/Mail_Scripts) by Andreas Amann no longer works on Lion or Mountain Lion. Can something be done on 10.8 or later to automate sending Apple mail?

Comment: There's another thread on here that askes the same question with several different answers.  [How can I send a Mail message later](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45604/how-can-i-send-a-mail-message-later).  Check it out, it may be of some help to you.

Comment: @jbharper2 Since the OP has indicated the old question doesn't work, we should presume there's good cause to ask a new question explaining that the old selected answer isn't workable. If someone has experience with MailScripts working - please answer that here and we can see how and if to handle a merge / edit to the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gmail and are willing to use the (I think very awesome) web interface, check out [Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/referral_download.html?ref=9fdks) for Gmail. It does everything you're asking for.

EDIT:

You can also use Automator to schedule (by delaying) when your message is sent. 
[image: screenshot]
The Pause function is very helpful, and Apple has a whole section for Mail in the library. I would save it as an application and then run it with Spotlight or Alfred or Launchbar whenever you need it.