# OS X Mail App - How to send an email at a specific date and time

Tags: mail.app

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, is there any way to create different emails and have them delivery automatically at a specific date and time?

As provider I do use iCloud.com and Gmail.com and I have OS X 10.10 Mail App.

Comment: Hi. You may want to look at this post as it provides a way of using Apple Script to add this functionality [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45604/how-can-i-send-a-mail-message-later)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for mail [SendLater](http://www.chungwasoft.com/sendlater/) unfortunately it costs money. Maybe there are some similar free plugins.